# Android cannot load image from URI using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

The Android app allows users to select a photo from their phone gallery which I save the URI to realm. I then retrieve this information and use Picasso to load it into the image view. For some reason the image is not loaded.

The URI is something like:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A333180
```

I save it to realm using `mCategory.icon = imageURI.toString()` and then when I load it:

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
                .load(Uri.parse(mCategory.icon)) // mCategory.icon is a string 
                .resize(200, 200)
                .error(R.drawable.mountain) // default image to load
                .into(viewHolder.categoryIcon);
```

Comment: That Uri is not valid Uri for image path.

Answer (score 5):

The URI you got is a `ContentProvider` URI to show it with Picasso you try to do this:

```
    File file = new File(Uri.parse(mCategory.icon));
    Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(file)  
            .resize(200, 200)
            .error(R.drawable.mountain) 
            .into(viewHolder.categoryIcon);
```

P.S: Though you can convert your `ContentProveder` path to `Absolute` path still it's better if you don't since Picasso support loading from the File..

Comment: Did you check your file? Check to see if the file is loaded correctly using file.exists()

Comment: how did you solve the problem. its good gesture to put your answer after you are done

Comment: I think you meant to post this comment under question, as this is The Answer (^^)

Answer (score 3):

Use `setLoggingEnabled(true)` in picasso to check the log if there is any error message.

Answer (score 1):

This is working perfectly with new version of Picasso **2.71828**

```
Picasso.get()
       .load(imageUri)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
       .fit()
       .centerCrop()
       .into(viewHolder.categoryIcon);
```

Comment: It's wrong that this answer gets downvoted. Its a perfect solution for the problem. The OP didn't mention the Android version he has trouble with. Although I believe he accidentally tried loading a contentUri, since Android Q there are only few situations where its allowed to load directly from the FileAPI because of the scoped storage concept. You have to load from the contentUri and this is supported in new Picasso 2.71828 - thats y I came here. So, whoever is migrating to Q and uses Picasso.with().load(file), use new Picasso and Picasso.get().load(contentUri). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned URI contains the encoded value of colon **:** i.e. %3A.

Either rename the source OR try [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or some other library to serve the purpose.